# ListView NullPointerException @ ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

i am currently getting a null pointer exception whenever my listview has 6 or more items in it && when i try to click on any listview row. Note: when i click on a listview row with less than 6 items everything works as intended.

Any help would be wonderful i've been stuck on this problem for a very long time = \ (about a month)

```
     12-16 04:11:34.309: W/dalvikvm(2028): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x95b62648)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$1.getView(AlertController.java:879)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2161)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1079)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-16 04:11:34.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Code Where I believe that I am getting this error is

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> 
{


    public MyListAdapter(){
        //Important 4 SO: customerItems is an arraylist of <Item> Objects
```

super(UserOrderMenu.this,R.layout.itemview, customerItems); //is this wrong?
        }

```
    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View itemView = convertView;

        if(itemView == null){ //makes sure we have a view to work with



            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.itemview,parent,false);


        } else{
            itemView = convertView;
        }

        //find the item to work with. using item class and customerItem ArrayList

        final Item currentItem = customerItems.get(position);


        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonTrashCan);
        imageview.setClickable(true);


        imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                remove(currentItem); 
                notifyDataSetChanged(); //this notifies the Arrayadapter to update

                float t1price, t2price, t3price, t4price, t5price;
                System.out.println(currentItem.getTopping1Used());

                if(currentItem.getTopping1Used()){      
                    t1price = currentItem.getTop1P();

                }else
                    t1price = 0;

                if(currentItem.getTopping2Used()){
                    t2price = currentItem.getTop2P();
                }else
                    t2price =0;

                if(currentItem.getTopping3Used()){
                    t3price = currentItem.getTop3P();
                }else
                    t3price = 0;

                if(currentItem.getTopping4Used()){
                    t4price = currentItem.getTop4P();
                }else
                    t4price =0;

                if(currentItem.getTopping5Used()){
                    t5price = currentItem.getTop5P();       
                }else
                    t5price =0;



                    findTotalPrice(-t1price,-t2price,-t3price,-t4price,-t5price,true);
                    findTotalPrice(-currentItem.getItemP());

            }
        });





        TextView n = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
            n.setText(currentItem.getItem().toString());



            // then currentItem.getTop1P();
        TextView p = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemPrice);

            p.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getItemP()));

            return itemView;
    }

}//end of MyListAdapter Class

   private void populateListView(){ //this is how to add an item to ListView
    customerItems.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null)); //remove later
    customerItems.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null,""));
    ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter;

    try{
         adapter = new MyListAdapter();
         ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }



}
```

Item.java:

```
public class Item {

private String item="none";
private float itemP=0;
private String top1="none";
private float top1P=0;
private String top2="none";
private float top2P=0;
private String top3="none";
private float top3P=0;
private String top4="none";
private float top4P=0;
private String top5="none";
private float top5P=0;


private boolean topping1used = false;
private boolean topping2used = false;
private boolean topping3used = false;
private boolean topping4used = false;
private boolean topping5used = false;

public Item(){
    super();
}

public Item(String item, float itemP){
    super();
    this.item = item;
    this.itemP = itemP;
}

public Item(String item, float itemP,String top1,float top1P,String top2,float top2P,String top3,
             float top3P,String top4,float top4P,String top5,float top5P)
{       
    super();


    this.item = item;

    this.itemP = itemP;
    //this is a price dont have to worry about it


    this.top1 = top1;
    this.top1P = top1P;


    this.top2 = top2;
    this.top2P = top2P;


    this.top3 = top3;
    this.top3P = top3P;


    this.top4 = top4;
    this.top4P = top4P;


    this.top5 = top5;
    this.top5P = top5P;
}

public Item(boolean t1, boolean t2, boolean t3, boolean t4, boolean t5){
    super();
    this.topping1used = t1;
    this.topping2used = t2;
    this.topping3used = t3;
    this.topping4used = t4;
    this.topping5used = t5;

}


//set 
public void setTopping1used(boolean topping1used) {
    this.topping1used = topping1used;
}

public void setTopping2used(boolean topping2used) {
    this.topping2used = topping2used;
}

public void setTopping3used(boolean topping3used) {
    this.topping3used = topping3used;
}

public void setTopping4used(boolean topping4used) {
    this.topping4used = topping4used;
}

public void setTopping5used(boolean topping5used) {
    this.topping5used = topping5used;
}




        //get 
public String getItem() {
    return item;
}

public float getItemP() {
    return itemP;
}

public String getTop1() {
    return top1;
}

public float getTop1P() {
    return top1P;
}

public String getTop2() {
    return top2;
}

public float getTop2P() {
    return top2P;
}

public String getTop3() {
    return top3;
}

public float getTop3P() {
    return top3P;
}

public String getTop4() {
    return top4;
}

public float getTop4P() {
    return top4P;
}

public String getTop5() {
    return top5;
}

public float getTop5P() {
    return top5P;
}

public boolean getTopping1Used(){
    return topping1used;
}
public boolean getTopping2Used(){
    return topping2used;
}
public boolean getTopping3Used(){
    return topping3used;
}
public boolean getTopping4Used(){
    return topping4used;
}
public boolean getTopping5Used(){
    return topping5used;
}


}//end of Item class


private void populateList(String item, float price,String t1n, float t1p, String t2n, float t2p,
                            String t3n,float t3p, String t4n, float t4p, String t5n, float t5p)
{

    customerItems.add(new Item(item,price,t1n,t1p,t2n,t2p,t3n,t3p,t4n,t4p,t5n,t5p));
    populateListView();
}
```

private void populateListView(){ //this is how to add an          item to ListView
        customerItems.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null)); //remove later
        customerItems.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null,""));
        ArrayAdapter adapter;

```
    try{
         adapter = new MyListAdapter();
         ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }



}
```

Comment: Pls be careful about code and question format.

Comment: The getView method is used to return the view of one of the list. It seems like you are doing a lot inside. Try to override getItem, and attach an onItemClickedListener to your adapter to do the rest of the logic in there. Hope this helps

Comment: @k3v1n4ud3 thanks i did this and it cleaned up my code, but i still get the null pointer

Comment: can anyone tell me why i get an error at line 394. which can be seen here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java.                                 From my limited understanding i would assume that this method should never even be called. And this is because i @override the getView method which subsequently calls the createviewfromresource method(line 394).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after forever debugging my program i finally found a solution. I will try to clearly summarize it here.

The problem: When i was calling Android's AlertDialog(of Multiple Choices items!) from my Listview it would crash my program.

The Solution: Instead of using Androids AlertDialog for Multiple choice items. I had to create my own custom version of multiple choice item selection. Then when i clicked on the listview to activate the alertdialog all was well again.

If you are calling a multiple choice alert dialog from a listview click, and you are experiencing the null pointer exception of android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394). Then try creating your own custom multiple choice selection!

Excuse my repetition hope this might help someone in the future.

Comment: I have had exactly the same problem using both `SingleChoice` and `Simple List`. In my case I am targeting at API21 with compatibility downto 15. The funny thing is that it seems to happen only when it needs to represent a scrollable list, I mean the list is a bit long.

Answer (score 2):

1) Your coding standards are not good, I suggest you to please improve on that

2) You didn't mention the problem correctly and the code you pasted is too much commented, as it's difficult to know what you are trying to achieve or you commented on purpose for pasting over SO.

3) Your getView() method implementation is wrong, check the correct way below:

```
if (convertView == null) 
{

    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.Your_Row_XML_File, null);

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1_in_row_xml_inflated_as_above);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

}
else
{
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

viewHolder.textView1.setText("Any string value");
```

whereas your ViewHolder contains view declarations of your views in your xml file:

```
private final class ViewHolder 
{
    public TextView textView1;
    public TextView textView2; // if any and add views like this
}
```

Refer examples and Android Docs to clear out understanding for the same, it will be good and give a good base to your code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure "your coding standards are not good" is particularly constructive criticism.

Comment: @krispy People tend to downvote and move on, while I tried to "suggest the guy to improve on that" and he/she did presented neatly(check for edits) as initially it was not at all readable. And also it depends on the person whether a suggestion is taken to improve him/herself or frowned upon that he/she is pin-pointed. My intention was to improve him/her by telling it in polite way and that's what I did. Don't take it in another way but please help me out with better sentence. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
 Context mContext;
List<Item> mItem;

public MyListAdapter(Context context,List<Item> item){
    super(context, item); 
   this.mContext =context;
  this.mItem=item;
}
@Override
    public int getCount() {

        return item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View itemView = convertView;

    if(itemView == null){ 
        itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.itemview, null); 


    }


    final Item currentItem = customerItems.get(position);



    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonTrashCan);
    imageview.setClickable(true);


    imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



        }
    });





    TextView n = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
        n.setText(currentItem.getItem.toString());


    TextView p = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemPrice);

        p.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getItemP()));

        return itemView;
}

  }
```

And for setting list view : And list is your List of Items  ;

```
     MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, list);
     ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

try with this and If doesn't work than comment :

Comment: on this line of code : super(context, item); i am getting the error of "The constructor BaseAdapter(context, item) is undefined.   Remove arguements to match baseAdapter.

Comment: so remove and check .

Comment: oh, well i previously did try that and when i ran it the listview did not show up at all.

Comment: in: MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, list); list is null or it have some values.

Comment: for mine list = customerItems (its an arraylist of Item objects) and i made sure that none of the item objects have values that are null.

Comment: list is an arraylist of Item objects.so give some value before showing list view. if it is null than listview will not show.

Comment: i believe i am doing that correctly i use this: (EDIT: this doesnt look nice so i reposted it at the very bottom of Item.java ) private void populateList(String item, float price,String t1n, float t1p, String t2n, float t2p,
        String t3n,float t3p, String t4n, float t4p, String t5n, float t5p)
 {
  
  customerItems.add(new Item(item,price,t1n,t1p,t2n,t2p,t3n,t3p,t4n,t4p,t5n,t5p));
  populateListView();
 }

Comment: what is this : customerItems.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null)); //remove later
    customerItems.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null,""));

Comment: this is how i previously tried to remove all null objects from my arraylist. It pretty much iterates through the arraylist and removes all the null objects it finds. I thought this would work but i still get the null pointer exception.